# Can my question be considered for re-opening?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, duplicate-questions

I asked a question many months ago, [Why didn't Geordi and Ro fall through the floor in "The Next Phase" episode of TNG?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/5798/2912), and it was closed as a duplicate of [How come Patrick Swayze didn't fall through floorboards in Ghost](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/2429/2912), which I found to be acceptable at the time.

However, I have since stumbled upon a completely unrelated post by @TangoOversway here on meta ( https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1546/2912 ), which hints at an answer to my earlier question, and demonstrates it is not a simple "intentional goof" (as the answer on the duplicate question suggests):

> For example, a frequently asked question about the *Star Trek: The Next Generation* episode *The Next Phase* is, "If Geordi and Ro could walk through walls, why didn't they sink through the floor?" It's a legitimate question and it's not addressed on screen, but Ron Moore has gone on record as saying they had an explanation involving surface tension, but it got cut.

Is this sufficient evidence to re-open the question?  And hopefully @TangoOversway, or someone else familiar with Ron Moore's "on-record" statements, can fill in an appropriate answer?

Comment: Those questions aren't anywhere near duplicates, and a **good** answer would only be tangentially related. I voted to reopen.

Comment: The *Ghost* question's answer explicitly covers the *TNG* question.  Although apparently with inaccurate information.  Personally, I'd reopen it if we had more than "they had an unused explanation" as that seems of minimal value as an answer.  Do we have information on what this "surface tension" explanation would have roughly been?

Comment: If it's re-opened, I'll be glad to provide that info as an answer with a little more background.

Comment: Thanks everyone for re-opening the question. And thanks to @TangoOversway for the answer!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There you go, it has been reopened.

Answer (score 3):

I think I've brought that point up several times about that particular episode.  I think, since there is an answer to this particular question about this particular situation, that it should be opened.

In this case, the writers did intend for this issue to have an explanation and it's also worth including the point I've made on this site that there are times when explanations are included, but when you're dealing with the limited time of an hour long TV show, technical explanations often have to take a back seat to other issues.

By the way, I have voted to re-open it.  If 3 others vote to reopen, it will be reopened.